# how to get userId when login into android studio project

Tags: java, android, webapi

I am working on an Android Studio project in which I get data from an API. I tried to get the data when I insert login information and get `userId` invisible, for example I want to put it in `Integer` instead of `TextView`. I have used `retrofit` to get data from the web API. When I tried to get the `userId`, I got an error with `int As Null value`. How can I solve it?

My web API code:

```
[HttpGet]
        public IHttpActionResult getUser(string userName, string passWord)
        {
            List<Person> api = new List<Person>();
            SqlConnection mainconn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MyConn"].ConnectionString);
            SqlCommand da = new SqlCommand("Select UserID, username, password from tblLogin where username = '" + userName + "' and password = '" + passWord + "'", mainconn);
            mainconn.Open();
            SqlDataReader dr = da.ExecuteReader();
            while(dr.Read())
            {
                api.Add(new Person()
                {
                    UserID = Convert.ToDecimal(dr.GetValue(0)),
                    username = Convert.ToString(dr.GetValue(1)),
                    password = Convert.ToString(dr.GetValue(2))
                });
            }
            var Response = new ApiResults
            {
                Results = api
            };
            if (api.Count > 0)
            {
                return Ok(Response);
            }
            else
            {
                return Ok("No Data Found");
            };
        }
```

My Java code:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    Button btnLogin;
    EditText edUsername, edPassword;
    TextView txtPersonEye;
    Integer id;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        btnLogin = findViewById(R.id.btnLogin);
        edUsername = findViewById(R.id.etUsername);
        edPassword = findViewById(R.id.etPassword);

        btnLogin.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                if(TextUtils.isEmpty(edUsername.getText().toString()) || TextUtils.isEmpty(edPassword.getText().toString())) {
                    String message = "Please Insert Username and Password";
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,message,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                } else {
                    LoginRequest loginRequest = new LoginRequest();
                    loginRequest.setUsername(edUsername.getText().toString());
                    loginRequest.setPassword(edPassword.getText().toString());
                    loginUser(loginRequest);
                }
            }
        });
    }

LoginRequest loginRequest = new LoginRequest();
        id = loginRequest.setUserId(loginRequest.getUserId());
        IdGet(loginRequest);

    public void IdGet(LoginRequest loginRequest)
    {
        Call<LoginResponse> loginResponseCall = ApiClient.getService().PersonEyeGet(id);
        loginResponseCall.enqueue(new Callback<LoginResponse>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<LoginResponse> call, Response<LoginResponse> response) {
                if(response.isSuccessful()) {
                    LoginResponse loginResponse = response.body();
                }
                else
                {
                    String message = "No User Found";
                    Toast.makeText(Visitor.this, message, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<LoginResponse> call, Throwable t) {
                String message = "User Data Missing";
                Toast.makeText(Visitor.this, message, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Login request:

```
public class LoginRequest {

    public Integer UserID;
    private String username;
    private String password;

    public Integer getUserID() {
        return UserID;
    }

    public void setUserID(Integer userID) {
        UserID = userID;
    }

    public String getUsername() {
        return username;
    }

    public void setUsername(String username) {
        this.username = username;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }
}
```

Login response:

```
public class LoginResponse implements Serializable {

    private Integer UserID;
    private String username;
    private List<LoginRequest> loginRequests = null;

    public Integer getUserID() {
        return UserID;
    }

    public void setUserID(Integer userID) {
        UserID = userID;
    }

    public String getUsername() {
        return username;
    }

    public void setUsername(String username) {
        this.username = username;
    }

    public List<LoginRequest> getLoginRequests(){
        return loginRequests;
    }

    public void setLoginRequests(List<LoginRequest> loginRequests) {
        this.loginRequests = loginRequests;
    }
}
```

ApiClient:

```
public class ApiClient {
    public static Retrofit getRetrofit() {

        HttpLoggingInterceptor httpLoggingInterceptor = new HttpLoggingInterceptor();
        httpLoggingInterceptor.setLevel(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY);

        OkHttpClient okHttpClient = new OkHttpClient.Builder().addInterceptor(httpLoggingInterceptor).build();


        Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .baseUrl("http://XXX.XX.XXX.X/webapi/")
                .client(okHttpClient)
                .build();

        return retrofit;
    }

    public static UserService getService() {
        UserService userService = getRetrofit().create(UserService.class);

        return userService;
    }
}
```

Any help in this matter is welcome.